# from product of swaps to product of disjoint cycles

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have permutation represented in this form: 
$X=(8,9)(14,15)(12,14)(13,15)$

Can I do the following steps?
$$X=(8,9)(14,15)(12,14)(13,15)\\
=(8,9)(14,12,15)(13,15)\\
=(8,9)(15,13,14,12)$$

I think that is wrong, but I don't understand why
Thanks much!

Comment: It looks good .

Comment: Did you change the permutation? Please re-edit, or roll-back, to the original permutation you posted. Add the second if you want.

Comment: I have just changed the numbers, that doesn't change anything seriously, how I think. Yes, of course, if it is necessary. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I think now it is ok. Sorry for that

Comment: Don't worry about it! It's not a problem. It's just that if you have answer(s), they might seem meaningless or inappropriate when you change the problem. ;-)  If you'd like to check one more permutation, post the initial representation, and what you end with, below my answer, and I'll check it over. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you've performed is correct:

Your first representation of $X$ is not expressed as the product of *disjoint* cycles.

The first equality holds, and follows from the fact that $\;(14, 12, 15) = (14, 15)(14, 12)$.
(But the resulting $X$ is not yet represented as the product of disjoint cycles.)

The second equality holds, and follows from the composition of the non-disjoint cycles $(14, 12, 15)(13, 15) = (15, 13, 14, 12)$

So the final representation of $X$ is as the product of *disjoint* cycles. And since every permutation can be represented *uniquely* as the product of disjoint cycles, there are nothing further to do other than expressing it as the equivalent (same) permutation, e.g. $(8, 9)(12, 15, 13, 14)=(8, 9)(15, 13, 14, 12)$, but there is no need to do so.

Comment: You're welcome ABCD!

Comment: Nicely done. :+)